# T-SQL Returning results with the most matching columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm hoping someone could point me in the right direction here. I have two
arbitrary tables:

```
    TableA                                  TableB  
    ----------                              ----------  
    (cola-int)  (colb-int)  (colc-char)     (cola-int)  (colb-int)  (colc-char)  
    1           10          Data1           1           NULL        Match1  
    2           20          Data2           2           NULL        Match2  
    1           10          Data3           2           30          Match3  
    2           30          Data4  
    2           30          Data5
```

The query:

```
    select a.cola, a.colb, a.colc, b.cola, b.colb, b.colc  
    from TableA a  
    inner join TableB b on b.cola = a.cola  
    where a.colb = b.colb or b.colb is null
```

Produces the following results:

```
    cola    colb    colc    cola    colb    colc  
    1       10      Data1   1       NULL    Match1  
    1       10      Data3   1       NULL    Match1  
    2       20      Data2   2       NULL    Match2  
    2       30      Data4   2       NULL    Match2  
    2       30      Data5   2       NULL    Match2  
    2       30      Data4   2       30      Match3  
    2       30      Data5   2       30      Match3
```

How can I only return the Match3 for Data4 and Data5 and
not the Match2 for Data4 and Data5, since they do not match
on colb? I want my result set to look like this:

```
    cola    colb    colc    cola    colb    colc  
    1       10      Data1   1       NULL    Match1  
    1       10      Data3   1       NULL    Match1  
    2       20      Data2   2       NULL    Match2  
    2       30      Data4   2       30      Match3  
    2       30      Data5   2       30      Match3
```

I've tried using outer joins to no avail and tried using an exclusive or
in the where with the following query:

```
    select a.cola, a.colb, a.colc, b.cola, b.colb, b.colc  
    from TableA a  
    left outer join TableB b on b.cola = a.cola  
    where (case when (a.colb = b.colb) then 1 else 0 end) +  
        (case when (b.colb is null) then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

which produces the following results:

```
    cola    colb    colc    cola    colb    colc  
    1       10      Data1   1       NULL    Match1  
    2       20      Data2   2       NULL    Match2  
    1       10      Data3   1       NULL    Match1  
    2       30      Data4   2       NULL    Match2  
    2       30      Data4   2       30      Match3  
    2       30      Data5   2       NULL    Match2  
    2       30      Data5   2       30      Match3
```

which still procude the Match2 for Data4 and Data5.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, is it "If there is more than one record for a distinct `TableA.colc` then only keep the record that has a `TableB.colb` value that isn't NULL"?

Comment: @JNevill - what I want to do is return the results that have 'TableA.cola = TableB.cola' and 'TableA.colb = TableB.colb'. If this doesn't provide a match, then only match 'TableA.cola = TableB.cola'. So just one or the other.

Comment: @Horaciux - the result table that I want is included in the question. Please see the table under 'I want my result set to look like this:'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this:

```
/* Test data. */
DECLARE @TA TABLE (cola int, colb int, colc char(10))
DECLARE @TB TABLE (cola int, colb int, colc char(10))

INSERT INTO @TA VALUES (1, 10, 'Data1')
INSERT INTO @TA VALUES (2, 20, 'Data2')
INSERT INTO @TA VALUES (1, 10, 'Data3')
INSERT INTO @TA VALUES (2, 30, 'Data4')
INSERT INTO @TA VALUES (2, 30, 'Data5')

INSERT INTO @TB VALUES (1, NULL, 'Match1')
INSERT INTO @TB VALUES (2, NULL, 'Match2')
INSERT INTO @TB VALUES (2, 30, 'Match3')
/* End Test data. */

/* First get all that match on both fields [cola] and [colb]. */
; WITH BothMatch As (
SELECT
    A.cola As acola
    , A.colb As acolb
    , A.colc As acolc
    , B.cola As bcola
    , B.colb As bcolb
    , B.colc As bcolc
FROM
    @TA As A
    INNER JOIN @TB As B
        ON A.cola = B.cola
        AND A.colb = B.colb
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    BothMatch

UNION

/* Then match all by [cola] that do not already exist in BothMatch. */
SELECT
*
FROM 
    @TA As A
    INNER JOIN @TB As B
        ON A.cola = B.cola
        AND B.colb IS NULL
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT 
            BothMatch.acola 
        FROM 
            BothMatch 
        WHERE 
            BothMatch.acola = A.cola 
            AND BothMatch.acolb = A.colb
    )
ORDER BY
    acola
    , acolb
```

Result:

```
acola   acolb   acolc   bcola   bcolb   bcolc
1       10      Data1       1   NULL    Match1    
1       10      Data3       1   NULL    Match1    
2       20      Data2       2   NULL    Match2    
2       30      Data4       2   30      Match3    
2       30      Data5       2   30      Match3
```

Comment: This does work, although a shorter method would be preferable. Thanks! Marking as answer but hoping for a shorter solution.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a stab at this after looking at the case statement version (that I think answers my question in the comments above).

You could solve this with either Windowing functions or a Correlated Subquery:

Window Function (comparing the b.colb to the max(col.b) for that a.cola to see if we want to 'keep' or 'drop' the record.)

```
SELECT
    acola,acolb,acolc,bcola,bcolb,bcolc
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            a.cola as acola,
            a.colb as acolb,
            a.colc as acolc,
            b.cola as bcola,
            b.colb as bcolb,
            b.colc as bcolc,
            CASE 
                WHEN 
                    b.colb = max(b.colb) OVER (PARTITION BY a.colc) OR
                    b.colb IS NULL AND count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY a.colc) = 1
                THEN 'KEEP' 
                ELSE 'DROP' 
                END AS KeepOrDrop
        FROM TableA a
        INNER JOIN TableB b ON b.cola = a.cola

    ) as c
WHERE c.KeepOrDrop = 'Keep'
```

Correlated Subquery (Where we find the max b.colb in a correlated subquery within the WHERE clause)

```
SELECT 
    a.cola as acola,
    a.colb as acolb,
    a.colc as acolc,
    b.cola as bcola,
    b.colb as bcolb,
    b.colc as bcolc,

FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b ON b.cola = a.cola
WHERE coalesce(b.colb,0) IN (SELECT max(coalesce(colb,0)) FROM TableB WHERE cola = a.cola)
```

Comment: Both of these queries are just returning the records that just match both cola and colb from both tables.

Comment: That's because of that WHERE statement that was stuck in there. I will remove it since the Correlated Subquery or Window function/Where will take care of it instead.

Comment: Pretty close. We're just missing those pesky NULL's then

Comment: I've changed them both up a bit to handle single null values. I think that should do it. I'm thinking there is a more elegant way to deal with this scenario with the NULL issue.

Comment: My previous comment was started before your final edits. Oops! Your queries still match Data2 and Match3, although acolb and bcolb do not match. I like the shorter code if it would take care of that one record.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorter way than [Uporabnik003's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35071160/1837122) to achieve this:

```
/* Test data - code by Uporabnik003 */
declare @ta table (cola int, colb int, colc char(10))
declare @tb table (cola int, colb int, colc char(10))

insert into @ta values (1, 10, 'Data1')
insert into @ta values (2, 20, 'Data2')
insert into @ta values (1, 10, 'Data3')
insert into @ta values (2, 30, 'Data4')
insert into @ta values (2, 30, 'Data5')

insert into @tb values (1, NULL, 'Match1')
insert into @tb values (2, NULL, 'Match2')
insert into @tb values (2, 30, 'Match3')
/* End Test data. */

;with cteAllResults as (
    select      a_cola  =a.cola
                ,a_colb =a.colb
                ,a_colc =a.colc
                ,b_cola =b.cola
                ,b_colb =b.colb
                ,b_colc =b.colc
                -- The "best" row of each joining group will get RowNo=1
                ,RowNo  =row_number() over  (   partition by a.cola,a.colb,a.colc 
                                                -- Depending on your real data, you may want 
                                                -- to play around with the order by clause 
                                                -- to identify the "best" row differently.
                                                order by b.colb desc
                                            )
    from        @ta     a  
    inner join  @tb     b   on a.cola   = b.cola  
                            -- This additional join clause is equivalent to your
                            -- `where a.colb = b.colb or b.colb is null`
                            and a.colb  = isnull(b.colb,a.colb) 
    )
select      *
from        cteAllResults
where       RowNo=1
```

It produces the exact same results as your question's desired output.

However, it's rarely correct to prefer "shorter" code over more performant code.  For starters, line count is affected a lot by comments and (semi-)arbitrary decisions about whitespace and code layout.

More importantly, Uporabnik003's solution will probably perform better than this over large datasets. This solution relies on first generating a rowset that is too big, then whittling it down; their solution builds up the correct rowset from two smaller sets.

If I had appropriate primary keys on the tables, I'd use Uporabnik003's solution but replacing the `where not exists` clause with a `left join`, testing for join failure (`null` on the right-hand side).